# Gstreamer, how to play udp stream using C on android?

Tags: android, c, udp, gstreamer, udpclient

I'm trying to play udp stream using Gstreamer on android. (I've used [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/-/tree/master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5) tutorial from the official Gstreamer [website](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/index.html?gi-language=c)). I can play rtsp and https streams, but when I pass udp uri (like this: `udp://@238.0.0.1:1234`) nothing happens (there is a black screen). In the log I have: `Error received from element uridecodebin1: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.` I've found some documentation [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pbutils/gstpbutilsinstallplugins.html?gi-language=c) about installing plugins, but I don't understand how to do that.

Here is the piece of the code I use:

```
data->context = g_main_context_new ();
g_main_context_push_thread_default (data->context);

/* Build pipeline */

data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin", &error);

if (error) {
 gchar *message =
    g_strdup_printf ("Unable to build pipeline: %s", error->message);
 g_clear_error (&error);
 set_ui_message (message, data);
 g_free (message);
 return NULL;
}
```

and the 2nd one:

```
/* Set playbin2's URI */
void gst_native_set_uri (JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jstring uri)
{
CustomData *data = GET_CUSTOM_DATA (env, thiz, custom_data_field_id);
if (!data || !data->pipeline)
   return;
const gchar *char_uri = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars (env, uri, NULL);
GST_DEBUG ("Setting URI to %s", char_uri);
if (data->target_state >= GST_STATE_READY)
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
g_object_set (data->pipeline, "uri", char_uri, NULL);

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars (env, uri, char_uri);

data->duration = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;
data->is_live |=
      (gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline,
                              data->target_state) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_NO_PREROLL);
```

}

Full code is [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/-/blob/master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c)

This is the first thing I'm doing in C and JNI, so I would be grateful for working code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've accidentaly found the solution. I just modified my `Android.mk` file by adding `$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED)` into `GSTREAMER_PLUGINS` line. Now udp streams works fine!